Using slug inside file that contains all routes with Auth.js
So besides the app routing system that comes with next 14, I am using Auth.js for authentication and I have all the protected and unprotected routes defined in a routes.ts file.
export const publicRoutes = [
"/",
"/auth/new-verification",
"/uploads",
"/products/:slug",
];
/** An array of routes accesible trought authentication*/
export const authRoutes = [
"/auth/login",
"/auth/register",
"/auth/error",
"/auth/reset",
"/auth/new-password",
];
/** Prefix for API authentication routes used for API authentication*/
export const apiAuthPrefix = "/api/auth";
/** Default redirect path after logging in*/
export const DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/settings";
Inside the publicRoutes I want to use a slug like "/products/[slug here]".Is there any way of doing that?
Using [slug] or :slug or stuff that works with the next file naming convention dosen't work.

Instead of trying to define a slug inside the routes.ts file I just changed the matcher in the middleware.ts file. From a matcher that caught all routes like:
matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],

I instead defined my routes inside the matcher like this:
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/auth/new-verification",
    "/uploads",
    "/auth/login",
    "/auth/register",
    "/auth/error",
    "/auth/reset",
    "/auth/new-password",
    "/api/auth",
  ],
};

